# Is there a faster alternative than groupby transform?

Tags: python, pandas

I just updated Pandas to 0.13.1 but now a line of code (that was already slow under 0.12.0) became unbearably slow. I wonder whether there is a faster alternative or not.

I use a dataframe. Let say I have something like this one:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'one'], 'B': range(6)})
print df

       A  B
0    one  0
1    one  1
2    two  2
3  three  3
4  three  4
5    one  5
```

I create a third column 'C' by grouping by 'A' first and choosing the last value of each group in B:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
print df

      A   B  C
0    one  0  5
1    one  1  5
2    two  2  2
3  three  3  4
4  three  4  4
5    one  5  5
```

The question is: is there a faster way to do it with Pandas version 0.13.1?

Thank you

Comment: I was going to suggest cumcount and tail(1), but you're after something else (these would be much faster). What are you trying to do where this is the bottleneck?

Comment: Actually it has to be a bug, not only slowness. With 600000 rows it use to take about one minute on my old laptop with Pandas 0.12.1. Now with Pandas 0.13.1 it still runs after 30 minutes...

Comment: Please post this with an example (probably with np.random.rand) we can test (the timings) on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is awaiting implementation: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6496

But you can do this:

Generate the data / groups:

```
In [31]: np.random.seed(0)

In [32]: N = 120000

In [33]: N_TRANSITIONS = 1400

In [35]: transition_points = np.random.permutation(np.arange(N))[:N_TRANSITIONS]

In [36]: transition_points.sort()

In [37]: transitions = np.zeros((N,), dtype=np.bool)

In [38]: transitions[transition_points] = True

In [39]: g = transitions.cumsum()

In [40]: df = pd.DataFrame({ "signal" : np.random.rand(N)})

In [41]: grp = df["signal"].groupby(g)
```

Here is the actual transform:

```
In [42]: result2 = grp.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])

In [43]: result1 = pd.concat([ Series([r]*len(grp.groups[i])) for i, r in enumerate(grp.tail(1).values) ],ignore_index=True)

In [44]: result1.equals(result2)
Out[44]: True
```

Timings.

```
In [26]: %timeit pd.concat([ Series([r]*len(grp.groups[i])) for i, r in enumerate(grp.tail(1).values) ],ignore_index=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit grp.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
1 loops, best of 3: 472 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for pointing that out. The grouping seems to work on the small toy example but the transforms do not (both). I get nasty KeyError: 0 and another NotImplementedError: messages.